# Where should I configure rails gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

For example, I use mobylette gem and it's [documentation](https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette) says that I can configure it like this.

```
 mobylette_config do |config|
    config[:fallback_chains] = { mobile: [:mobile, :html] }
    config[:skip_xhr_requests] = false
    config[:mobile_user_agents] = proc { %r{iphone}i }
 end
```

Only problem is that, I don't know where to put that code. I tried creating new file config/initializers/mobylette.rb, but I got no method 'mobylette_config' error when starting rails server.

So where should I put these gem configurations and specifically in this case mobylette configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the conventional place to put it -- config/initializers

You can also check that its being loaded by putting in a logger.debug in the initializer

logger.debug 'LOADED mobylette configuration'

You can quickly test if there's another problem by putting the config in your environment.rb file (which is not where I'd leave it)

Both of those should give you some more info to debug

Answer (score 3):

This had me pulling my hair out too.  But digging around in the source on github:

https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette/blob/master/lib/mobylette/respond_to_mobile_requests.rb

I found this in the comments:

```
  # Example Usage:
  #
  #   class ApplicationController...
  #     include Mobylette::RespondToMobileRequests
  #     ...
  #     mobylette_config do |config|
  #       config[:fall_back] = :html
  #       config[:skip_xhr_requests] = false
  #       config[:mobile_user_agents] = proc { %r{iphone|android}i }
  #       config[:devices] = {cool_phone: %r{cool\s+phone} }
  #     end
  #     ...
  #   end
```